# Detectar posible memory leak en animación canvas HTML 5

Tags: javascript, html5, canvas, animación

Intento encontrar un (supuesto) memory leak, la animación se supone que muestre una serie de grafos en cada frame, pero lo que hace (al parecer) es no liberar el array de grafos y sigue dibujando todo cada vez que pasa un frame, haciendo la animación muy lenta.

Código de ejemplo (abrir con cuidado ya que puede trabar el navegador con el tiempo):

```
let c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
let ctx = c.getContext("2d");
let grafos = []

function randomGraph() {
    return {
        x: Math.random() * 500,
        y: Math.random() * 500,
        w: 5 + Math.random() * 70,
        h: 5 + Math.random() * 70
    }
}

function middleX(g) {
    return g.x + (g.w / 2)
}

function middleY(g) {
    return g.y + (g.h / 2)
}

function draw() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 500);

    let c = 2 + Math.trunc(Math.random() * 5)
    let columns = c

    grafos.length = 0
    for (let i = 0; i < c; i++) {
        grafos.push(randomGraph())
    }

    ctx.fillStyle = "#FFFFFF"
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 500, 500);

    ctx.fillStyle = "#00FF00";

    for (let i = 0; i < grafos.length; i++) {
        ctx.strokeStyle = "#0000FF";
        //ctx.beginPath() // <-- aca arregla el problema
        ctx.fillRect(grafos[i].x, grafos[i].y, grafos[i].w, grafos[i].h);
        ctx.rect(grafos[i].x, grafos[i].y, grafos[i].w, grafos[i].h);
        ctx.stroke();
    }

    ctx.lineWidth = 2;
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#FF0000";

    for (let y = 0; y < columns; y++) {
        for (let x = 0; x < columns; x++) {
            let index = (y * columns + x) % grafos.length
            let index2 = ((y + 1) * columns + (x + 1)) % grafos.length
            //console.log('index', index, index2)
            //ctx.beginPath() // <-- aca arregla el problema
            ctx.moveTo(middleX(grafos[index]), middleY(grafos[index]))
            ctx.lineTo(middleX(grafos[index2]), middleY(grafos[index2]))
            ctx.stroke()
        }
    }

    window.requestAnimationFrame(draw)
}

window.requestAnimationFrame(draw)
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-nex6wm?file=index.html

Intente limpiar el array, ponerlo solo dentro de la función draw pero no pasa nada.

Edit: poniendo un log se ve que no es el array, el length se ve correcto. Es algo con el canvas...

Comment: El código debe ir en la pregunta, agrégalo con el botón que indica `{}`.

Comment: gracias, ya lo agregue

Answer (score 0):

Ok leyendo un poco encontré la solución
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/stroke#re-stroking_paths

"Typically, you'll want to call beginPath() for each new thing you want to stroke. If you don't, the previous sub-paths will remain part of the current path, and get stroked every time you call the stroke() method."

Traducción:

"Tipicamente, querrás llamar beginPath() para cada nueva cosa que quieras dibujar. Si no lo haces, las sub-rutas previas permanecerán en la ruta actual, y serán dibujadas cada vez que llamas el metodo stroke()."

No sabía que hacía falta poner ctx.beginPath(), ahi puse en el código original (comentado) donde agregué para solucionarlo.

Comment: En lugar de editar el código en la pregunta, pon lo que agregaste en esta respuesta. Además, traduce lo que has encontrado.

Comment: Si puse que agregue ctx.beginPath()